# how to change existing appname from firebase sms verification. %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

how to change existing appname from firebase sms verification. %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.

Comment: from my research, you can't. Which I think is crazy because you have your users then see xxxyyyy.firebaseapp.com which I think looks really bad. Hopefully I am wrong